# sqlite3_prepare_v2 failed (Xcode sqlite 3)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

I'm so trying to connect the sqlite but can't. Can someone help me? I don't see any error here at all and I've searched high and low for this problem on google and here but I can't find any way to fix this.

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Database_Implementation_using_SQLite_%28Xcode_4%29)

Do help me, I'm going crazy over this error. =(

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

sqlite3 *contactDB;  //declare pointer to database structurery
const char *dbPath = [databasePath UTF8String];  //convert NSString to UTF8String

//open database file. TRUE = success, FALSE = failed
if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &contactDB)== SQLITE_OK){     
    NSLog(@"Opened");

sqlite3_stmt *statement;
NSString *querySQL =  @"SELECT address, phone FROM contacts";
const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, 1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Statement is OK");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Statement FAILED");
}

}else{
    NSLog(@"Failed");
}
```

The log only reads "Opened" then "Statement FAILED"

Comment: 1. Why do you use a constant NSString and then -[UTF8String]? If it's a constant query, you'd better use a constant C string. 2. Why the complicated sqlite_prepare_v2 way? I doubt you need *that* much customization.  There's a function called sqlite3_exec(). 3. Example of me using this: http://github.com/H2CO3/libsqlitemanager

Comment: Next time, when posting a question related to objective-c, remember to add the objective-c tag. It tells the code highlighter that the code is actually in objc, not sql / some other language.

Comment: Change that NSLog to `NSLog(@"Statement FAILED (%s)", sqlite3_errmsg());`

Comment: Does your sqlite database file actually exists on `databasePath`?
You need to copy the .sql file to the **CACHE** directory of your app prior to using the database.

Comment: What is the return code from the prepare operation??

Comment: I am facing similar issue, mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916124/sqlite3-prepare-v2-exc-bad-access-in-ios-10

Any suggestion what is wrong !!

Answer (score 6):

This is how I do it. (Compiled piece of my database class)
Shows you the sql error too.

```
sqlite3 *_database;
sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &_database);

NSString *sqlStatement = @"SELECT address, phone FROM contacts";
const char *sql = [sqlStatement UTF8String];
static sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, sql, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);
if(result != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Prepare-error #%i: %s", result, sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
}

result = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
if (result != SQLITE_DONE) {
    NSLog(@"Step-error #%i for '%@': %s", result, sqlStatement, sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
}

sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
```

Comment: it said no table found. I checked sqlite thru terminal, it's there.

Comment: If you're working on the simulator, try removing the .sql file from your filesystem and then retry, if you're working on a device; delete the app and try again. Maybe the .sql file on the device's sandbox is outdated

Comment: where do i find that sql file? the database file i have is .db format. like the tutorial taught me

Comment: If you run it in the simulator: /Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simluator/<ios version>/Applications/<app identifier>/<Documents|Library/Caches>

Comment: Keep in mind you HAVE to copy your database to your `Caches` directory before you're able to use it. Like so: http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

Comment: hmm at <user>, i don't have Library at all. All i have are Desktop, Downloads, Movies, Music, etc. and the database files are just saved at user/<user>/

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this line of code.

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, 1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
```

The `1` is wrong.  From the SQLite docs:

```
int sqlite3_prepare_v2(
  sqlite3 *db,            /* Database handle */
  const char *zSql,       /* SQL statement, UTF-8 encoded */
  int nByte,              /* Maximum length of zSql in bytes. */
  sqlite3_stmt **ppStmt,  /* OUT: Statement handle */
  const char **pzTail     /* OUT: Pointer to unused portion of zSql */
);

If the nByte argument is less than zero, then zSql is read up to the first zero
terminator. If nByte is non-negative, then it is the maximum number of bytes
read from zSql.
```

So you are forcing SQLite to only read the first byte from the statement.  Of course this is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure these points you have done in your project.

1. Verify the file is listed under "*Copy Bundle Resources*" under your Target's "*Build Phases*" and NOT under "*Copy Files*" with a custom destination or sub-path.
2. Make sure you don't have any path conflicts with your sqlite file.I mean document `directory/database path/` are correct.
3. And I have implemented sqlite query like

   `SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE status LIKE 'someString' AND BankName LIKE 'someString'`
   Instead of
   `SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE status='someString' AND BankName='someString'`
4. Make sure you have not included your sqlite file in any other application
5. Make sure you don't have duplicate sqlite files with same path.

This is worked for me after lot of struggle, I hope it helps some one. Please up vote if it helps.